# Share ImageMagick files over network drive without users installing ImageMagick?

Tags: python, imagemagick, installation

Is it possible to share ImageMagick files with others over a network drive (ex.: Z:), without having the users install ImageMagick?

ImageMagick works fine on my own machine as I used its binary installer and set up Windows environment variable ("MAGICK_HOME").

I tried using Python to auto setup the user's system environment variable, but even then when user types in command prompt:

```
convert c:\testA.psd c:\testB.png
```

it'll give an error:

> convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format 'PSD' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
>
> convert.exe: no images defined 'c:\testB.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.

and related error such as:

> RegistryKeyLookupFailed 'CoderModulesPath'

**Note**

- System: Windows 7, 64bit
- ImageMagick version: 6.9.0-Q8
- ImageMagick folder contains many files, include CORE_RL_*.dll,
  dcraw.exe, ffmpeg.exe, convert.exe, compare.exe, etc. and "modules"
  folder

**Reference #1**

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20599

Some commands that help debug IM. I used

```
convert -list format
```

and it returns an empty list. So now I'm sure the user's IM isn't properly installed.

**Reference #2**

[Packaging an application that uses the ImageMagick C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050347/packaging-an-application-that-uses-the-imagemagick-c-api)

I was searching for answers more along the line of 'manually install ImageMagick' (not through binary installer) so i can know exactly what Windows settings I have to configure through Python. Then the link above (posted by Alex) shows what I want. And now I realized I did not configure the environment variable "CoderModulesPath". Now I'm going to try it out...

Comment: You mean binary files, like display, identify, convert from imagemagick?

Comment: yes, the entire ImageMagick folder containing imdisplay.exe, identify.exe, convert.exe and all those DLLs, modules folder, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best chance to achieve that is to share the portable version of ImageMagick. Look up ImageMagick portable on Google, download the files and put them on a share.

Comment: Thanks!! Never thought there'd be a portable version! Will try that out too :)

Comment: ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/    look for that ZIP. it's the 16bit portal version. Though I can't find any 8bit version :/

Comment: The 16 bit won't do the job?

Comment: Thanks!! It does the job :)

Answer (score 2):

After a long search... finally found a solution:

If you want to share your ImageMagick folder and files with other users - to save them the hassle of installation or for some other reasons - be sure to programatically configure their system's environment variables:

1. "MAGICK_HOME" = [path to the ImageMagick folder]

   **ex. z:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q8**
2. "MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH" = [path to the ImageMagick folder]\modules\coders

   **ex. z:\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q8\modules\coders**

in the **...modules\coders folders**, there are DLLs that process different types of image files, and if you don't specify this path, IM can't find "decode delegate"

After the environment variables are set, you might want to inform the user to restart their machine in order for the variables to take effect.

### Compatibility

If you are using API to access this ImageMagick library (ex. Python wand), then this might be a good way to go. The portable version of ImageMagick may not be compatible since the file structures are different from the non-portable.

### Resources

Python class that retrieves and modifies Windows registry keys and values:

Reference: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577621-manage-environment-variables-on-windows/

```
if sys.hexversion > 0x03000000:
    import winreg
else:
    import _winreg as winreg

class Win32Environment:
    # Utility class to get/set windows environment variable
    def __init__(self, scope):
        assert scope in ('user', 'system')
        self.scope = scope
        if scope == 'user':
            self.root = winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
            self.subkey = 'Environment'
        else:
            self.root = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
            self.subkey = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'

    def getenv(self, name):
        key = winreg.OpenKey(self.root, self.subkey, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
        try:
            value, _ = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, name)
        except WindowsError:
            value = ''
        winreg.CloseKey(key)
        return value

    def setenv(self, name, value):
        # Note: for 'system' scope, you must run this as Administrator
        key = winreg.OpenKey(self.root, self.subkey, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, name, 0, winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(key)
```

Comment: That is a working solution at the cost of modifying user's machine settings which is what an installation is about after all. Good job though.

Comment: Thanks Tarik! The portable version is definitely useful, and I hope they can keep updating it to be more compatible with lots of the existing IM APIs, though I don't know how that's possible at the moment.